# Why we still observe leakage at gate when we ground source. drain, and body of NMOS?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, physics

Why we still observe leakage at gate when we ground source. drain, and body of NMOS? I think it has something to do with the gate oxide or capacitors but im not sure

Comment: how much leakage and how does it compare with the leakage specifications in the datasheet for that device?

Answer (score 3):

If all nodes are grounded (or at equal potential), then there cannot be any leakage without an added power source.

If the gate-source voltage is non-zero, there can be a small leakage in the gate oxide. This is negligible in most applications, and only important in very fine geometry integrated circuits.

Comment: Or in circuits that drive the gate far too hard, either by erroneously applying too high a gate voltage or by parasitic elements in a bad PCB layout causing the gate voltage to ring too high. You can get several microamps of Fowler-Nordheim tunnelling before the part actually fails outright.

Comment: Or in circuits where you are measuring signals in the low femptoamps or attoamps, which I do. In these cases, I have to get unpackaged dice and wire-bond. Epoxy packaging leaks like a sieve. And FET gates are still worse.